# How can I access a cudafied method from a different class?

Tags: c#, .net, cudafy.net

So I have 2 classes, both classes call CudafyTranslator.Cudafy and cudafy their appropriate methods. The resulting modules are then added to the GPU. Why does cudafy keep giving me a compile exception when I call one cudafied method from one class, from within a cudafied method of another class. I know I can call cudafied methods from other cudafied methods within the same class, so why doesn't this work?

```
//Class 1:
public class Class1
{
    [Cudafy]
    public static void method1()
    {
        //Do stuff.
    }
}

//Class 2:
public class Class2 
{
    [Cudafy]
    public static void method2() 
    {
        Class1.method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe the exception also?

Comment: Cudafy.CudafyCompileException, it says "Line 2: warning: OpenCL"

Comment: Hmm, it 's just a warning, not error if I am correct?

Comment: @Nhan Phan It is an exception, the text of the exception just gives me a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source look OK. I tested from my side with cudafy.net version **1.29.5576.13786**. I guest you can update your cudafy.net, and then clean and rebuild your solution will help.

Regard!